# tv connected, laptop monitor should turn off

Tags: nvidia, screensaver, tv

Have HP nvidia 7400M gpu laptop with VGA connected to sony TV.

Have been using ubuntu with my Sony LCD for 4 years. Earlier in 2011-12 the screensaver would run on the monitor and switch it off even while the VLC would run normally on TV.
Firstly I hate the fade system of screensaver. Secondly, I only want to turn of my monitor not TV. now both are turning off. This was never an issue before, now its happens with 2014 ubuntu. I had reformatted and got latest ubuntu.

How do i switch off my monitor when VLC or youtube fulscreen is running on my TV?